# pySpark question: map/parallelize not working as expected

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I have a python function which takes data, processes data and returns a value.

Another python function which takes a tuple of data & broadcasted dataframe, processes data and saves it on disk.

Except for the map/parallelize, all other code uses pandas

This is how I originally wrote the code

```
Class X:
    Def DoSomething(tup):
        Process Data &
        Return X

    Def DoAnotherThing(tup):
        Process Data and Save 

    Def main():

        Create tupList ( created a List of tuples)   

        rddData = spCon.parallelize(tupList).map(lambda p: self. DoSomething (p))

        t = rddData.collect()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(args)
```

The above code does not work if I invoke main as above. DoSomething function will return all None

If I change the code to implement directly in **main**

```
Def DoSomething(tup):
    Process Data &
    Return X

Def DoAnotherThing(tup):
    Process Data and Save 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Create tupList ( created a List of tuples)   

    rddData = spCon.parallelize(tupList).map(lambda p: DoSomething (p))

    t = rddData.collect()
```

The above code however returns appropriate data.

Can someone please help me understand why I see such behavior.

The reason I am trying to create an instance of the class and invoke main is because I am trying to pass arguments to the python script, but I am not sure if I can do that without calling the main() function categorically.

Comment: For Classes, you need `def __init__(...):`, not `main()`

Answer (score 0):

See this simple example to help you

```
class X():
    def __init__(self, sc):
        data = [1, 2, 3]
        rddData = sc.parallelize(data).map(lambda p: self.DoSomething(a=p))
        self.t = rddData.collect()

    def DoSomething(self, a):
        return a + 1

ex = X(sc=sc)
ex.t
# [2, 3, 4]
ex.DoSomething
# <bound method X.DoSomething at yadda yadda
```

Comment: .looks like obviously need to remember my basics. thanks a lot.